# How to conditionally compile in case of an existing table?

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl, preprocessor-directive

I'm working with Progress-4GL, release 11.6, appBuilder and procedure editor.

I have just created a table, called "table_X", and I'm using it inside the code, something like:

```
FIND table_X ...
```

However, my program is general, but the table is custom-based (some customers have this table, but some don't).

So, I'd like to add a "preprocessor", something like:

```
&IFDEF table_X
&THEN FIND table_X ...
&END
```

Where the `&IFDEF` means: "Only compile this piece of code if that table exists in DB".

Is this possible in Progress-4GL, release 11.6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using static queries you will need to add a define in an environment include used when compiling. In your standard directory:

```
// env.i

// nothing (yet)
```

And in your customer directory:

```
// env.i

&global define table_x
```

Which you can then use at compile time with your `propath`, if your propath starts with the customer directory then the definition is picked up, otherwise env.i is taken from your standard directory and table_x is not defined:

```
{ env.i }

&if defined( table_x ) &then
   find table_x no-lock.
&endif
```

If you can replace static use of this table with dynamic use, then you do not need the definitions and you can:

```
def var hb as handle no-undo.

create buffer hb for table "table_x" no-error.
if valid-handle( hb ) then do:
   hb:find-unique( no-lock ).
end.
```

While this could be attractive, it does mean that you are burdening all your customers with potentially irrelevant run-time checks.