# How to replace static "query" way of working by dynamic "queries"?

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl, dynamicquery, dynamic-queries

In this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66472235/how-to-conditionally-compile-in-case-of-an-existing-table), I asked how to handle the situation where a table might be defined or not. The proposed solution I'm trying to follow, is working with dynamic "queries" instead of static ones. Unfortunately I have no idea how to do this, can anybody help me with this? Let me give you an example:

Static way of working:

```
FIND Table1 WHERE Table1.field1          = 123
                AND Table1.field2        = Current-Table.field2
                AND UPPER(Table1.field3) = "Constant-string"
                AND Table1.field4        = temp-table.field4 NO-ERROR.
IF NOT AVAILABLE Table1
  THEN DO:
           CREATE Table1.
           ASSIGN Table1.field1 = 123
                  Table1.field2 = Current-Table.field2
                  Table1.field3 = "Constant-string"
                  Table1.field4 = temp-table.field4.
           RELEASE Table1.
       END.
```

Dynamic way of working:

```
CREATE BUFFER h-Table1 FOR TABLE "Table1" NO-ERROR.
IF VALID-HANDLE(h-Table1)
THEN DO:
         L-Found = h-Table1:FIND-FIRST("WHERE Table1.field1 = " + STRING(123) + 
                                         "AND Table1.field2   = " + STRING(Current-Table.field2) +
                                         "AND UPPER(Table1.field3) = 'Constant-string'" + 
                                         "AND Table1.field4 = " + temp-table.field4) NO-ERROR.
         IF NOT L-Found
         THEN DO:
                  h-Table1:BUFFER-CREATE("").
              END.
         ELSE MESSAGE "FOUND".
     END.
```

Is it `BUFFER-CREATE` or some other method, how should I fill in the parameters (like `ASSIGN Table1.Field1 = 123`), ...?

Comment: Beware that you are replacing a static UNIQUE find with a dynamic FIRST find. Also when concatenating queries you really want to use SUBSTITUTE and QUOTER to prevent query injection.

Comment: @StefanDrissen: I don't understand your remark, but I just found out that the following query seems not to be working: `h-Table1:FIND-FIRST("WHERE Table1.field1 = " + STRING(field1_value) +   "AND Table1.field2   = " + STRING(field2_value) + "AND UPPER(Table1.field3) = 'FIX_STRING'" + "AND Table1.field4 = " + temp_table.field4) NO-ERROR.`, is this what you are talking about, how can I solve this using `SUBSTITUTE` and `QUOTER` (isn't that last a typo?)?

Comment: Start by removing NO-ERROR, since this will also hide syntax errors in your query. quoter is not a typo, I'll add what your find-unique should look like to my answer.

Comment: @StefanDrissen: the query, based on the `QUOTER()` function (I'm not using `SUBSTITUE()` yet) is working fine, but when I try to delete a table record, I fall into runtime error 335. For this, I've created a new StackOverflow post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66489158/how-can-i-delete-a-record-in-a-table-based-on-dynamic-queries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
def var hb as handle no-undo.

create buffer hb for table "mytable".
hb:buffer-create().
assign
   hb::myfield = 123
   hb::another = "ok"
   .
hb:buffer-release()

finally:
   delete object hb no-error.
end finally.
```

Note that hb::myfield is shorthand for

```
hb:buffer-field('myfield'):buffer-value
```

And also beware that when using dynamic objects, you are responsible for garbage collection. If you create it, you need to delete it.

Dynamic find-unique part:

```
def var hb     as handle  no-undo.
def var lfound as logical no-undo.

create buffer hb for table 'Table1'.

lfound = hb:find-uniqe(
            'where field1 = 123'
            +  ' and field2 = ' + quoter( current-table.field2 ) )
            +  ' and upper( field3 ) = "constant-string"'
            +  ' and field4 = ' + quoter( temp-table.field4 ) 
         ) no-error.
```

or using a substitute:

```
lfound = hb:find-unique(
            substitute(
               'where field1 = &1':u
               +  ' and field2 = &2':u
               +  ' and upper( field3 ) = &3':u
               +  ' and field4 = &4':u,
               123,
               quoter( current-table.field2 ),
               quoter( 'constant-string' ),
               quoter( temp-table.field4 )
            )
         ) no-error.
```

You will soon want to create a query builder class / function to handle creating queries and possibly also handling run-time validation which you are now also responsible for.

Comment: You are also more responsible for transaction control, since the AVM cannot automatically scope transactions for dynamic buffers.

Comment: Also also, the `CREATE BUFFER` statement only works like the `DEFINE BUFFER` statement if you use the `BUFFER-NAME` clause (found when dealing with leaky record scopes).