# How can I delete a record in a table, based on dynamic queries?

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

This question is a follow-up of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66473331/how-to-replace-static-query-way-of-working-by-dynamic-queries).

I currently have following piece of source code:

```
    CREATE BUFFER h-Table1 FOR TABLE "Table1" NO-ERROR.
    IF VALID-HANDLE(h-Table1)
    THEN DO:
             L-Found = h-Table1:FIND-FIRST("WHERE ...
             IF L-Found
             THEN h-Table1:BUFFER-DELETE().
```

When I launch the `BUFFER-DELETE()` command, I have error 335 (`The Table1 record has NO-LOCK status. DELETE not allowed. (335)`). How do I need to alter my source code in order to make this work? (How can I alter the status of my Table1 record?)

Comment: You may want to read the documentation on the buffer handle https://docs.progress.com/bundle/openedge-abl-reference-117/page/Buffer-object-handle.html and from there read about the method you are using.

Comment: @StefanDrissen: although your reference to the documentation is correct, I must say that the documentation is very limited: e.g. the particular case we're dealing with there, treats about the `BUFFER-DELETE()` method. The problem I mentioned, can be handled using the `EXCLUSIVE-LOCK` parameter, but neither that parameter neither the runtime error are mentioned in the corresponding documentation (https://docs.progress.com/bundle/openedge-abl-reference-117/page/BUFFER-DELETE-method.html).

Comment: The find-first method as available from the buffer handle page describes the syntax FIND-FIRST ( predicate-expression [ , lockmode[ , waitmode]] )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
h-Table1:FIND-FIRST ("WHERE ....", EXCLUSIVE-LOCK) .
```

or after the first find (which should have been done with explicit NO-LOCK option)

```
hTable1:FIND-CURRENT (EXCLUSIVE-LOCK) .
```