# Is there a way to use preprocessor directives in Progress-4GL?

Tags: preprocessor, openedge, progress-4gl

I'm working with Progress-4GL, release 11.6.

As explained in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66473331/how-to-replace-static-query-way-of-working-by-dynamic-queries), I'm now using dynamic queries, like this:

```
CREATE BUFFER h-Table1 FOR TABLE "Table1" NO-ERROR.
IF VALID-HANDLE(h-Table1)
...
```

I have put this piece of code in an `*.i` file, which I include as:

```
{incl\include_file.i}
```

I would like to put this include file only at certain customers' systems. This, however, would cause compilation problems at the other customers.

Is there a way to say (C-style preprocessors):

```
#IF <condition>
#THEN {incl\include_file.i}
```

If yes, what are the conditions I can use in such a preprocessor directive?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which compilation problems? What you are showing will run fine for everyone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, see the [documentation](https://documentation.progress.com/output/ua/OpenEdge_latest/pdsoe/PLUGINS_ROOT/com.openedge.pdt.langref.help/rfi1424920209949.html).

```
&if <whatever> &then
   { incl/include_file.i }
&endif
```

Are you deploying source code to your customers' systems? If not, then a preprocessor will not help you since it is evaluated as part of the `compile` statement. You can see the results of preprocessing when you compile a file with the preprocess option, the result is your source code with all preprocessors evaluated.

Comment: I'm indeed deploying source code on my customers' systems. I just checked the documentation link you referred to, but I don't find the condition I'm looking for here: is there a preprocessor directive which is capable of verifying if a certain table exists in the DB structure?

Comment: No, you can only do this at run-time. But upon startup / deployment / whenever you feel like it, you could generate a ``&global-define`` per "interesting" table in the database, include that and use it.